# Confusing simulation result when looking at Standard Errors

Tags: standard-error

Say from some normal distribution, $N$, a sample is pulled of length $n_1$.  From that sample, the sample mean and the standard error of the mean are calculated ($\sigma_\bar{x_1}$).  Many additional samples, of length $n_1$, are drawn from $N$ and the mean is calculated for each.  For each additional sample mean, a z-score is calculated against the original standard error, $\sigma_\bar{x_1}$.

My questions is, why is the resulting distribution of z-scores not a standard normal?  In simulating this exercise, I'm seeing distributions of z-scores that are wider than standard normal (picture).  Am I missing something obvious?

[image: Distribution of z-scores]

Comment: Could you explain why you expect a Normal distribution and not something closer to a Student t distribution?

Comment: Well, since the standard error of the mean is normally distributed (I think?) and subsequent observations of the mean would be well modeled be that standard error distribution.

I also tried to model the z-score historgram with t-distributions and they weren't any better.

Comment: @whuber on second thought you are absolutely correct.  I misunderstood where the t-distribution was relevant.